# List comprehension: If, then, and returning 1 value with Haskell

Tags: haskell, if-statement, io

```
findMatch :: [String] -> [String]
findMatch xs =
    let keywords = [("data", "set")]
    in [ if null x then "null" else fst y | x <- xs, y <- keywords, (snd y) == x]
```

Everything in this function works except for the *then*. If the (snd y) can't be matched to x (the x is drawn from a list of words sent by the user), I'd like to return a string that says "null."

```
in [ if (snd y) == x then fst y else "null" | x <- xs, y <- keywords]
```

Writing the list comprehension this way (thanks byorgey) works better, but then "null" is returned more times than I need it to be when more than 1 set of words are used in my keywords variable. I only need the string "null" to return once.

Maybe Haskell has a kind of break that I could add?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you add an example input and output? I'm new to Haskell but I'm hoping to help you figure this one out.

Comment: Userinput could be "search for a set", and this list comprehension see the word "set", and return the word "data" which is used by another part of my program. But if no matches can be found, I want it to return "null" which will trigger another part of the program. The comprehension works fine. The then just isn't working right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
let keywords = [("data","set")]
in [maybe "null" fst $ find ((== x) . snd) keywords | x <- xs]
```

unless the `keywords` list can contain several pairs with the same second component and you want them all listed, then it would be

```
in concat [case [key | (key,word) <- keywords, word == x] of { [] -> ["null"]; ms -> ms; } | x <- xs]
```

In the first case, it would be nicer if the `keywords` pairs were swapped,

```
let keywords = [("set", "data")]
in [fromMaybe "null" $ lookup x keywords | x <- xs]
```

Comment: I think that's it. I'm testing it out now.

Comment: This did the trick! Only one problem remaining: This function seems to cancel out the other functions I have that do the same thing but with other keywords. But I think I can figure out a solution. I'm going to try to put all of the functions into 1 function. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Making the keyword list an argument of the function might be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem lies in your understanding of list comprehension. Try the following:

```
[(x, y) | x <- [1,2,3], y <- [1,2]]
```

This does a Cartesian product, returning `[(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2), (3,1), (3,2)]`.

The easiest way to get what you want (if I understood you correctly) is probably write the recursion yourself. It also might very well be possible to do it with a combination of list functions.

Comment: My list comprehension does exactly what I want it to do. The only problem is that (in the second example) it returns "null" more times than I need it. I only need it to return once.

Comment: @Subtle If what you mean is that `xs=["s1", "s3"]`, `keywords=[("d1","s1"),("d2","s2")]` gives you something like `["d1", null, null, null]` it is because list comprehension produces every possible combination of `(x,y)`, i.e., a Cartesian product. The answer by pmr indicates why the first way doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe I could append the result to a list, and then return only the first element in that list? It wouldn't be the most elegant solution, but it would rectify the problem.

Comment: @Subtle Well since list comprehension already does a nested loop kind of thing, you might as well search `keywords` for each element in `xs`. I'm not sure how your suggestion is going to work, seems you want a list of (duplicate) results for each element in `xs`, but how are you going to keep track of them?

Comment: There wouldn't be much to keep track of because there are only 2 possible outputs: a string from the keywords variable, or the string "null." I'm going to try to see what happens when I split this into 2 separate functions.

Answer (score 2):

`null x` would only return false if a list is empty. Here you are applying null to `[Char]` a.k.a. `String`. But you predicate in the list comprehension prevents x from ever being something else than equal to the 2nd element of the tuple in the `keywords`.

In a list comprehension, an element is only included, when it matches all predicates.